# Last "available" month with data in SQL

Tags: sql, date, zoho

I have monthly data been imported and I need to show only the latest available data (only that month). If I use for ex. Getdata()-1, this does not really work as the data comes in between 1st and 15th of next month (May data is submitted between 1st and 15th of June).

Is there a way to get the data from the last month that is populated (if null, it would go one month back and so on)?

What I am using right now:

```
    case
             when "source indicator"  = 'Total Revenues'
             OR "source indicator"  = 'Total Opex'
             OR "source indicator"  = 'Month end cash balance'
             AND    month("date")  = (month(getdate())-1) then "EUR Amount"
             else "Amount"
         end as "YTD EUR Amount",
```

Table structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7gZu.jpg

Comment: Which dbms and can you share the table structure, please?

Comment: I am using Zoho Reports (not sure what dbms). I added the table screenshot above. Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: Well, the answer could vary depending on whether your zoho report is reading from sql server or mysql or .... But basically, you want something like month("date") = month(MAX("date"))

Comment: I found a page where it says that Zoho supports almost all SQL dialects: https://zohoreportsapi.wiki.zoho.com/Supported-SQL.html. Thanks

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about zoho, but can you try what I suggested  month(MAX("date"))  ? If it can't be put inline (the way you put (month(getdate())-1) ), it might be possible in a separate query in the same file, or in a subquery?